# Angular JS - Route to Non Single Page SPA

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, pushstate

We need to load some pages in non SPA mode, while others in SPA mode. For example, homepage and about pages should be non SPA, while other pages should be SPA.

**$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);** makes all pages SPA, even though route is not found. Not adding that line makes all pages non SPA.

How do I set up routing so that if a route is not present the page should be fetched from the server? i.e. not be pushstate.

Also, we're using ui-router.

Comment: I would say that such thing is not possible using angular-routings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I tweaked the previous answers and found a workaround

Basically, when the server is called for an SPA or non SPA page, the page needs to somehow indicate what mode it is running in. I choose a javascript variable for that

```
var html5mode = true;// for SPA, set to false for non SPA. Emit this from the server.
```

In your routedefs.js or where ever you have the routes defined.

```
// enable html5Mode for pushstate ('#'-less URLs)
if (html5mode) {
     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
         // reload if route not found.
         window.location = window.location;
     });

     $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
} else {
     $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
}
```

Comment: You could just $locationProvider.html5mode(html5mode) and eliminate the 'else'.  Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

Using ui-router, you can have an otherwise state. In that otherwise state, you can add a resolve that can do a request to the server to handle the routing :

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("otherwise");

$stateProvider
  .state('otherwise', {
    url: '/otherwise',
    template: 'some html',
    resolve : {
      serverPage: function servePage() {
        //http request to the server to fetch and redirect. 
      }
    }
  })
```

Comment: That did not work. For some reason this disables html5Mode and then everything hits the server.

Answer (score 1):

not sure why the earlier answer with an 'otherwise' state did not work, since that seemed promising. if you have multiple non-spa pages to go to, and you want to manage all of that in routes, you can also just pass in a function to otherwise(), rather than define a separate state, like so:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
    // redirect here, for example…
    window.location.href= window.location.origin + $location.url();
});
```

So that if the user navigates to the following route

http://mydomain.com/spa#/nonspa

It would be redirected to

http://mydomain.com/nonspa

(assuming 'nonspa' in not a valid route)

That said, I might just do a direct link to the non-spa page instead of going through the routing code -- seems simpler and faster.

Comment: Unfortunately this causes infinite reloads. If I hit http://mydomain.com/nonspa directly, after the page loads the otherwise function is executed, causing a reload.

Answer (score 1):

Would adding a target="_self" attribute to the anchor tag allow you to go from the SPA page to a non-SPA page?